# Common Lisp Debugging at the Reader Level

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am not exactly sure how to phrase this question properly. However, it goes something like this.

Suppose that we have some macros that work similar to `defun` in Common Lisp and are built on top of that. I made a declaration with one of such macros, and it compiled just fine.

However, when I made a call at the REPL, I got `NIL` as the result. That seemed puzzling, so I evaluated the original declaration at the REPL. It evaluated to `NIL`.

I need to debug this. My question is whether I should be looking at the reader level or somewhere else. That is, if there is no error thrown, where could I look to begin troubleshooting this?

Comment: Are you sure that `NIL` is an unexpected result? Many operators that are used just for a side effect don't return any useful value. If you're defining a function, you don't need to return anything (although the standard `DEFUN` macro returns the function name).

Comment: @Barmar please see my comment under one of the answers for why I expect a non-NIL response. Essentially, I would like to get the Common Lisp function object printed back.

Comment: I think that to debug this in any useful way you need to show us the definition.  We can't really be expected to explain why some form returns a given value if we don't know what that form is.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `MACROEXPAND` function to see what your macro call is expanding into.

```
(pprint (macroexpand '(my-defun ...)))
```

Comment: If your macro expands into a macro defined by CL, whose expansion you may not want to see as it may involve internal stuff, you can also use `MACROEXPAND-1` which does a single step of expansion.  (Barmar knows this, this comment is for the person who asked the original question.)

Comment: I use SLY/SLIME, so I have been using this feature via the front-end.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something such as the macroexpand-1 function and i'll explain why that's better than a normal macro expansion:

```
CL-USER> (defmacro our-when(test &body body)
   `(if ,test
    (progn
      ,@body)))
OUR-WHEN
CL-USER> (macroexpand-1 '(our-when(> 2 1)(format t "Hello World")))
(IF (> 2 1) (PROGN ((FORMAT T "Hello World"))))
T
CL-USER>
```

Here we create a macro and we can actually see how the macro expands the expressions within it. It's preferable at times when debugging to use macroexpand-1 vs. using macroexpand because macroexpand will also breakdown any macro that you have within your macro (like the built-in Common Lisp macros). Macroexpand-1 will limit the breakdown to the macro that you created.

Comment: I have tried that. The problem is that the macro seems to expand to something reasonable. What's more, if I change the name of the thing I am declaring to another one, I returns non-NIL. That is why I started wondering whether I can debug this at a lower level.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Add the macro to the question, and show the different results.

Comment: Is that the actual result you're getting? There seems to be an extra set of parentheses around `(FORMAT T "Hello World")` in the output.